# Dataflow FixedWindow triggered more than once during allowed period

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have lots of devices that constantly send me data. I want to use dataflow to parse the data and save it to Firestore. I want to use FirestoreIO for saving. First problem I ran into was that I started to constantly get error

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: the same document cannot be written more than once in a single request
```

It kinda makes sense since FirestoreIO is saving in batches and if there are multiple documents with same ID then you should get an error. So my next though was to group all device data with the same keys using GroupByKey PTransform. To do that I needed to create window before grouping. I want my window to collect all data during 1s period and then pass it all to GroupByKey step. My pipeline looks like this.

```
Window<KV<String, Device>> windowing =
                Window.<KV<String, Device>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
                        .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(
                                AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                                        .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(1))
                                        .alignedTo(Duration.standardSeconds(1))))
                        .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
                        .discardingFiredPanes();

PCollectionList.of(subscription1).and(subscription2)
                .apply(Flatten.pCollections())
                .apply("Parse pubsub", ParDo.of(new PubsubMessageParser()))
                .apply("Apply windowing", windowing)
                .apply("Group message", GroupByKey.create())
                .apply("FirestoreParser", ParDo.of(new FirestoreParser()))
                .apply(FirestoreIO.v1().write().batchWrite().build());
```

I see from logs that FirestoreParses step is sometimes run more often than once per second for one specific key.

```
INFO 2023-08-22T14:07:45.146Z running FirestoreParser for key 111111 : batch size 5
INFO 2023-08-22T14:07:45.192Z running FirestoreParser for key 111111 : batch size 2
INFO 2023-08-22T14:07:46.283Z running FirestoreParser for key 111111 : batch size 4

INFO 2023-08-22T14:07:48.150Z running FirestoreParser for key 111111 : batch size 6
INFO 2023-08-22T14:07:48.194Z running FirestoreParser for key 111111 : batch size 2
INFO 2023-08-22T14:07:49.271Z running FirestoreParser for key 111111 : batch size 5
```

Because of that my dataflow still sometimes throws the `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: the same document cannot be written more than once in a single request`  exception.

Why is this happening? I guess the problem lies within window or its trigger. How can I fix it so that the FirestoreParser would actually run once per second for specific key?